# Copy file from shared directory with given user name and password

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Is there a way to create/copy a file to/from specific network shared directory with different than current user name and password ?

Comment: LogonUser + ImpersonateLoggedOnUser + CopyFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I use to connect and map a remote drive to a local drive letter (along with the corresponding unmapping operation). Once you've mapped the drive to a drive letter, you copy just like you would with any other drive:

```
function MapNetworkDrive(const RemoteName, LocalDrive, 
  UserName, Password: string): Boolean;
var
  NetRes: TNetResource;
  Res: DWord;
begin
  Result := True;
  FillChar(NetRes, SizeOf(TNetResource), 0);
  NetRes.dwType := RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
  NetRes.lpRemoteName := PChar(RemoteName);
  NetRes.lpLocalName := PChar(LocalDrive);
  Res := WNetAddConnection2(NetRes, PChar(Password), PChar(UserName), 0);
  Result := (Res = NO_ERROR);
  if not Result then
    SysErrorMessage(Res);
end;

function TForm1.UnmapNetworkDrive(const LocalDrive: string): Boolean;
var
  Res: DWord;
begin
  Res := WNetCancelConnection2(PChar(LocalDrive), 0, True);
  Result := (Res = NO_ERROR);
end;
```

Example use:

```
begin
  if MapNetworkDrive('\\192.168.1.56\C$', 'H:', 'fred', 'password') then
  begin
    try
      // Do whatever between local drive and drive 'H:'
    finally
      UnmapNetworkDrive(Local);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: this is great way to do it, but it will show for a while a disk added to the my computer, and the user shall have rights to change there directly the files - something which i must prevent at all cost :|

Comment: Ah... That wasn't part of your specification. :)

Answer (score 1):

Either what @Luke suggested in a comment, or you can PInvoke to [NetUseAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370645%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function. You can pass user name and password in a call to NetUseAdd and then all attempts from current user session to access resources on this file share will use those credentials. [See example](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/netapi32/NetUseAdd.html) on pinvoke.net on how to call it -- you will have to translate this to Delphi.

Comment: No need to P/invoke from Delphi, it's native win32

Answer (score 1):

Alternately you could use the Windows API `CreateProcessWithLogon()` ([Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).